# neo4j not starting after disk full

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

My neo4j server fails to start after I had a 'no space left on device' error. Unfortunately, the last backup is 2 days old. 
This is neo4j 2.0.0 used in a webapp via spring-data-neo4j. Is there anything that can be done to recover the database? The log is attached, but I guess its to generic to give real help.

```
 org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@39931f5e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:509) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:164) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:267) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.IoPrimitiveUtils.readAndFlip(IoPrimitiveUtils.java:122) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.Command.readDynamicRecord(Command.java:326) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.Command.readDynamicRecords(Command.java:279) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.Command.readPropertyBlock(Command.java:249) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.Command$PropertyCommand.readPropertyRecord(Command.java:1022) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.Command$PropertyCommand.readFromFile(Command.java:965) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.Command.readCommand(Command.java:1456) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource$CommandFactory.readCommand(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:505) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogIoUtils.readTxCommandEntry(LogIoUtils.java:177) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogIoUtils.readLogEntry(LogIoUtils.java:114) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogIoUtils.readEntry(LogIoUtils.java:91) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.readEntry(XaLogicalLog.java:858) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.doInternalRecovery(XaLogicalLog.java:794) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:219) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:174) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaContainer.openLogicalLog(XaContainer.java:64) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:383) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]

Comment: I have restored the backup from 2 days ago. Thanks anyone who helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early versions of 2.0 have a known issue when running out of disc space - this has been resolved with recent versions. You can recover by manually fixing the datastore - however this is a time consuming operation requiring lot of knowledge on the internals of Neo4j.

Comment: So, you recommend to upgrade to a newer version to recover? I 'm not sure that the spring-data-neo4j version will work with the newer server..
I noticed that the database is rather large (a few GB, but if I do an online backup, than this backup is much smaller.. the most space is in the logcal.log files.

Comment: No I don't think there's an automated way to recover. You can try to start the graph.db directory with 2.0.4. But I'm not sure if that will work. To prevent fast growth of graph.db directory configure logical logs keep period, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-logical-logs.html. Spring Data Neo4j should play nicely if you just upgrade the bugfix version (aka from 2.0.2 -> 2.0.4).